# Emulator in android studio not working..it shows this error..What should i do?

Tags: android

emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to use the Intel HAXM accelerator, you need to go to Tools >> Android >> SDK Manager and then scroll down to find

> **Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator**

Then install it. If your emulator still doesn't work, try restarting Android Studio.

Or, there should be a little icon that looks lke this [Android SDK Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb8uv.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The package that needs to be installed is as highlighted in this [screenshot link](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-FnwQFIM1MpU/U3nqJIshpiI/AAAAAAAADzM/XW8DeWpHZsQ/s1600/HAXM_install_from_SDK_manager.png)

```
Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator
```