# Error in launching AVD With Lollipop on Windows

Tags: android

I have Windows 7  as well as  Android SDK and Eclipse. It works but the problem is that when I Create AVD With Intelx86, Android 5.1 and launch it it shows this error: it shows same screen for Phone as well as for Android Wear.

emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

I Have Avast antivirus on my machine. somewhere i read avast blocks intel HAXM acceleration. i tried with disabling Antivirus. but its not works.

Comment: Posible repeated [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883732/emulator-in-android-studio-not-working-it-shows-this-error-what-should-i-do)

Comment: Hello, regina. I was trying to install intel Haxm . but its not done yet

Answer (score 0):

Don't simply disable avast, you either have to uninstall it or go to settings > troubleshooting > disable virtual something. Remember, even if you have installed the HAXM with the sdk uploader,  you must find the .exe file in your sdk folder and execute it. If you have to do any software changes (like the above mentioned avast change) you must restart your computer before you can install the HAXM software to your computer.

Comment: I tried with these too, but it still shows like these                                       Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!